# Regex expression in apache configuration file

Tags: regex

I need to make sure that if a user hits `"//"` instead of `"/"`, it should be handled by regex in apache config for some urls. For ex -

`"http://www.mysite.com//home/index.jsp"` URL should be redirected or treated as `"http://www.mysite.com/home/index.jsp"`

Can you please throw some light on what regex I should be using in the apache config to make sure this works perfectly?

Comment: Are you expecting many users to be typing in URLs by hand? (Genuinely curious, not trying to be sarcastic.) That would sort of go against hypermedia...

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls/8381#8381):

> If you're using Apache with mod_rewrite, there is a pretty simple fix:
>
> ```
> # remove multiple slashes anywhere in url 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$ 
> RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
> ```
>
> This will issue a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently redirect so that any double slashes are stripped out of the URL.

Comment: Thanks Joey, Their is already a rewrite rule and condition mentioned in my httpd.conf and I tried using above solution just below the already existing condition/rule  as -   <br>RewriteEngine On</br>
<br>  RewriteOptions inherit </br>
<br>  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)[.] domainname.project.net$ [NC]</br>
<br>  RewriteRule (^/.*.jsp$) /project/%1$1 [PT]</br>

<br>## remove multiple slashes anywhere in url </br>
 <br> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$</br>
<br>  RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L] </br> but it's not working ! </br> Can you please let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is you are posting code in a comment. I'm not even trying to read that, honestly. If it's relevant to this question, then edit it into your question; if it's another problem entirely, then ask a new question.